# In pandas, how do I get multiple slices of a MultiIndexed-dataframe at a time?

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas, I'm familiar with how to slice a Multi-Index with a list to get multiple values, like such:

```
(Pdb) df = pd.DataFrame({"A": range(0,10), "B": -1, "C": range(20,30), "D": range(30,40), "E":range(40,50)}).set_index(["A", "B", "C"])
(Pdb) df
          D   E
A B  C         
0 -1 20  30  40
1 -1 21  31  41
2 -1 22  32  42
3 -1 23  33  43
4 -1 24  34  44
5 -1 25  35  45
6 -1 26  36  46
7 -1 27  37  47
8 -1 28  38  48
9 -1 29  39  49
(Pdb) df.loc[ [0,1,2]]
          D   E
A B  C         
0 -1 20  30  40
1 -1 21  31  41
2 -1 22  32  42
```

But how can I do this for multiple levels at a time?

```
(Pdb) df.loc[ [0,1,2], -1]
*** KeyError: -1
```

Or ideally:

```
(Pdb) df.loc[ [0,1,2], [-1]]
*** KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([-1], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: Try: `df.loc[([0, 1, 2], [-1]), :]`

Comment: Kindly post the expected output dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use tuple to slice your dataframe and you have to specify both index and columns indexes to allow Pandas to slice correctly your dataframes:

```
#               A       B   v-- all columns
>>> df.loc[([0, 1, 2], -1), :]
          D   E
A B  C         
0 -1 20  30  40
1 -1 21  31  41
2 -1 22  32  42

#               A        all B           C         v-- all columns
>>> df.loc[([0, 1, 2], slice(None), [20, 22, 24]), :]
          D   E
A B  C         
0 -1 20  30  40
2 -1 22  32  42
```

More information: [MultiIndex / advanced indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html)